# Delay in processing command from socket listener

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sockets

I have a special socket listener, that works in it's thread. It's job to get commands from external program that updates database. When command comes on socket i am calling special method, that updates my application cache from database.

I have a problem, that is delay between sending command from external program and processing that command in my app (ASP .NET Application). Every day my app restarting at 4 a.m. and by the end of the day i have delay about 1-2 hours.

How i can reduce this delay?

You can find code of my listener below.

Thanks.

```
public delegate void OnECIGetCommand( string command );

public class ECIMain
{

    protected Socket socket;
    protected string ip;
    protected int port;

    private static ECIMain INSTANCE = null;

    const int receivedDataSize = 250;
    protected static byte[] buffer = new byte[ receivedDataSize ];  
    protected static StringBuilder sb;                              

    protected static DoWorkEventHandler onCommand;              

    private ECIMain() 
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    private void StartSocket()
    {
        sb.Clear();
        socket.Listen(1);
        socket.BeginAccept(null, receivedDataSize, 
               new AsyncCallback(AcceptReceiveDataCallback), socket);
    }

    private static void AcceptReceiveDataCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // End the operation and display the received data on the console.
        byte[] Buffer;
        int bytesTransferred;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(out Buffer, 
                         out bytesTransferred, ar);
        HandleBuff(bytesTransferred, Buffer);

        // Create the state object for the asynchronous receive. 
        handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, receivedDataSize, 
                SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void HandleBuff(int size, byte[] buff )
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff, 0, size));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read more data.
            var content = sb.ToString();
            int pos = -1;
            if ((pos = content.IndexOf("</cmd>")) > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client.
                pos += 6; 
                if( pos < content.Length )
                    content = content.Remove(pos);


                var startPos = content.LastIndexOf("<cmd>");
                if( startPos > -1 ) 
                {
                    if (startPos > 0)       
                            content = content.Remove(0, startPos);
                    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                    worker.DoWork += onCommand;
                    worker.RunWorkerAsync(content);

                }
                sb.Remove(0, pos); 
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        SocketError error;
        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar, out error );

        if (error == SocketError.Success)
        {
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                HandleBuff(bytesRead, buffer);
                handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, receivedDataSize,
                        SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), handler);
            }
            else 
            {
                handler.Disconnect(true);
                INSTANCE.StartSocket();
            }
        }
        else if (error == SocketError.Shutdown || error == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
        {
            INSTANCE.StartSocket();   
        }
    }

    public static string InitECI(int port, DoWorkEventHandler commandHandler)
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
        {
            INSTANCE = new ECIMain();
            INSTANCE.port = port;
            onCommand += commandHandler;
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList
                  .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            INSTANCE.ip = ipAddress.ToString();
            try
            {
                INSTANCE.socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException e)
            {
                if (e.SocketErrorCode == System.Net.Sockets
                                         .SocketError.AddressAlreadyInUse)
                {
                    //INSTANCE.socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
                }
                throw e;
            }
            INSTANCE.StartSocket();
        }
        return INSTANCE.ip;
    }

    public static void ShutDownECI()
    {
        if( INSTANCE.socket.Connected )
            INSTANCE.socket.Disconnect(false);
        INSTANCE.socket.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the TCP Stack (either sending or receiving) one must look at the stack as it's own system, which is bullet proof and works very well...  Most of these types of issues deal with the fact that the application layer is easily able to fire off as many async actions as it wants, but that doesn't mean the TCP Stack is going to be faster, especially if it's overwhelmed.  What it means instead is that it will queue up and process tasks as it's able.

One of the symptoms of the stack being overwhelmed is the presence of many half session states visualized via the Netstat command.  Anything that has the word "Wait" is an indicator of a half state.  This occurs when one side posts a packet but the other doesn't respond right away.  From there it's all downhill because TCP kicks in and attempts to keep the sessions alive by re-sending the same packet. Multiply this by the number of active sessions and the fact that TCP retries up to 10 times for each packet before timing out, you can see this is the last thing an overwhelmed stack needs.

Your situation could be that the network traffic is exceeding the capacity of the single Network adapter.  This is usually solved by adding more network cards and using other means to do load balancing.  One way is what they call DNS round robin and it's the least expensive.  The other way is an F5 device.

Bottom line, it sounds like your network adapter is being overwhelmed.

Here's few things to check at both side of the wire.

- Are all of the sockets being fully closed when the gig is up for each session?
- Are you able to run a network monitor to review the overall loads... You typically want 60% or less utilization on any single network adapter.
- If your loads are too high then you can talk to DNS folks about using round robin, and put in another card into the same server (it will have different address)
- Sometimes it's due to lack of compression of the data being sent on the wire. You can investigate compression techniques too.
- Sometimes switches go bad which give MAC-To-MAC connect-ability.
- Improper router configuration can allow for re-tranmissions on the wire from different access points.
- Incorrectly configured servers can also broadcast too much noise (total junk)
- Wireless Access Points are notorious for going flaky they could be the source of noise too.

There's a lot to getting to the root of this type of issue, but hope that some of these ideas will help you.